# R-Squared for trends

Tags: forecasting, r-squared, test-for-trend

I am currently working on a problem of time series forecasting where I want to evaluate a model's predictions based on how accurately it captures the trend with respect to the absolute values as opposed to the magnitude itself, which I am not concerned about in terms of say, the MSE/RMSE with respect to the actual values.

I understand that R-squared, which is a measure of goodness of fit for linear use-cases could be a good evaluation metric. However, are there any other evaluation metrics which I could look at to purely assess the predictive strength of my model from a trends POV?

I was thinking about doing a percentage change over the predicted results and the actual results, and then computing the R-squared of the predicted percentage change and the actual percentage change of my out-of-sample dependent variable. Would that be the right way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi: I think you need to be more specific when you say "capture the trend". There are ways that prediction accuracy is calculated so you need to know what the error is that you're calculating in order to get a metric for it. Is the error just  (predicted - actual) for example ?. Essentially,  it's not clear to me on how the trend enters the problem ? If you're predicting a trend, the error can still be (predicted -actual).

Comment: Hi, sure I suppose that the way that I framed the question might be a bit confusing. What I am trying to achieve is as follows - if I have a predicted set of results, I want to compare it with the actual results such that, if the predicted result at time, i, has an uptrend and the actual result at the same time has an uptrend the evaluation metric should classify that as a 1, same if the prediction at time i is a downtrend and actual at time i is a downtrend too. If the prediction is an uptrend, and the actual is a downtrend it should be a zero. Averaging this over all predicted (1/2)

Comment: and actual results should tell me if the predictions were able to match the actual out-of-sample values. If I were to use the predicted-actual or any variants of this, I would factor in the magnitude as well, which is somewhat misleading in my analysis, when what I really want to do is see if the trends match. (2/2)

Comment: so you're looking to forecast whether the observation is an increase or decrease from it's previous value. Is that right ? When you get it right,  what are you giving a 1 to ?  When you get it wrong, what are you giving a zero to ? Is that a loss function ? If so, I would think it would be the other way around. It sounds like you're trying to predict direction so I would google for "metrics used when predicting direction".

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct in this. I found another metric which I think is a good metric for my analyses - mean directional accuracy (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_directional_accuracy). Thanks, once again! :D

Comment: great. I'm glad it helped.